# Assertion failed error in matchTemplate using OpenCV?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, computer-vision

Here is my code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_rgb = cv2.imread('snail.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread('human.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

Here is the error :

```sh
$ python image.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "image.py", line 10, in &lt;module>
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:1109: err
or: (-215:Assertion failed) _img.size().height <= _templ.size().height && _img.s
ize().width <= _templ.size().width in function matchTemplate
```

[image: Error]

Comment: The message seems to imply that your template is larger than the img_gray image. Template matching needs an image that is at least as large or larger than the template in both dimensions.

Comment: thank you very much, it works